# No pstricks output using xelatex after recent update

Tags: xetex, pstricks, update

I recently updated my miktex packages. When running Xelatex after the update I noticed that my pstricks output was either missing or completely messed up. Is this a bug in one of the updates? How can I fix this?

Comment: You will have to wait a few days. There is a known bug. You can try to use instead of the xdvipdfmx.cfg in generic/pstricks the orig cfg in the same folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PSTricks drawing not working with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614129/pstricks-drawing-not-working-with-xelatex)