# PSTricks drawing not working with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pdfpages

Consider the following (non-minimal) example `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}

% Atommodel.
\psset{dimen = m}
\newcommand*\bane[1]{%
  \rput{#1}(3.15,3.55){%
    \psellipse[
      linestyle = dashed,
      linewidth = \pslinewidth
    ](0,0)(3.55,1.05)}}
\def\elektron(#1,#2){%
  \rput(#1,#2){\psBall{white}{0.7ex}}
  \rput(#1,#2){\psBall{green!70!black}{0.5ex}}
  \rput(#1,#2){\tiny$-$}}
\def\proton#1#2{%
  \rput(\fpeval{3.15+#1*cosd(#2)},\fpeval{3.55+#1*sind(#2)}){\psBall{red}{2ex}}
  \rput(\fpeval{3.15+#1*cosd(#2)},\fpeval{3.55+#1*sind(#2)}){$+$}}
\def\neutron#1#2{%
  \rput(\fpeval{3.15+#1*cosd(#2)},\fpeval{3.55+#1*sind(#2)}){\psBall{blue}{2ex}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{pspicture}(6.3,7.1)
   % Elektronbaner.
   \bane{30}
   \elektron(5.07,5.48)
   \bane{90}
   \elektron(3.94,1.24)
   \bane{150}
   \elektron(0.75,4)
   % Kerne.
   \multido{\iA = 30+120, \iB = 90+120}{3}{%
     \neutron{0.5}{\iA}
     \proton{0.5}{\iB}}
   \neutron{0}{0}
   % Betegnelser.
  {\psset{linecolor = orange}
   \pscircle[
     linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth
   ](3.15,3.55){0.95}
   \rput(1.3,6.5){%
     \shortstack[c]{%
       Atomkerne/\strut\\[-0.75ex]
       nukleon\strut}}
   \psline{->}(1.3,6)(2.5,4.2)}
   \rput(0.9,0.6){Elektron}
   \psline[linecolor = green!70!black]{->}(1.8,0.6)(3.8,1.2)
   \rput(5.5,0.6){Proton}
   \psline[linecolor = red]{->}(5.5,0.85)(3.65,3.25)
   \rput(5.5,6.5){Neutron}
   \psline[linecolor = blue]{->}(5.5,6.25)(3.6,3.8)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it using `latex test.tex` --> `dvips test.tex` --> `p2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY test.ps` everything is fine. However, when I compile it using `xelatex test.tex` the drawing is "destroyed".

I need to use `xelatex` or something similar which can be used with the [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package. How do I get around this?

**Update**

With Ulrike's help, it's now working for me.

Comment: It is already reported several hours ago.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614078/87876

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay Thanks for pointing me to the other question. I will let my question stay in case someone has a workaround for my problem, i.e., use another engine or something similar.

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/zauguin/luapstricks and lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see my update to the question.

Comment: Well did you read the readme of the github?

Comment: When you write it like this, I guess my answer should be "not good enought". `:-)` I'm not sure what I've missed.

Comment: well the readme clearly says that this is experimental and what to do when you get an error. But your example works fine for me, so check if you really put the lua in the folder and not some html.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 2021-09-12

The bug has been resolved in 2021/09/10 v3.08 `PSTricks'.

---

PSTricks with XeLaTeX is currently broken, but the maintainer knows it already.

As an alternative you can try LuaLaTeX with the *experimental* `luapstricks` from https://github.com/zauguin/luapstricks.
You example works fine for me with it.

Comment: Can put as a note that this works on a local TeX installation and NOT on overleaf?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg please don't misuse such a question for personal support by updating at every new problem. Ask a new question if you have new problem.

Comment: it works fine for me, check if you have the newest luapstricks version.

Comment: The above example still does NOT work on just updated my MikTeX installation and the XeTeX engine. It seems like \rput(x,y){z} ignores x,y. My pstricks version is 2022/01/09 v3.13 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv).   With the LuaTeX engine it works fine, however.