# Pstricks compiled with XeLaTex with many errors, but return a pdf file

Tags: pstricks, compilation-error

Consider the following code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,margin=1cm,fontscale=1]{baposter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{yunit=.5cm,xunit=0.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.2)(22,7)
   \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(20.5,6.5)
   \def\f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add}
   \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,linecolor=yellow](8,2.5)(20.5,3.5)
   \rput(21,0){$n$}
   \rput(0,6.8){$a_n$}
   \psplot[plotpoints=21,linecolor=blue,linestyle=none,showpoints=true]{0}{20}{\f}
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](8,0)(8,6)
   \rput(14,70){\red$n\geq N$}
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,85)(16,85)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](0.05,2.5)(20.5,2.5)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](0.05,3.5)(20.5,3.5)
   \psline[linecolor=blue](0,3)(20.5,3)
   \uput[l](0,3){\blue$\ell$}
   \rput(17,4.5){$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}a_n =\ell$}
\end{pspicture}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.2)(13,3.5)
   \psset{xunit=0.5cm, yunit=.025cm}
   \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(16,130)
   \def\f{.5 x mul x mul x add 1 add }
   \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow=red,linecolor=yellow](12,130)(16,85)
   \rput(16.3,0){$n$}
   \rput(0,135){$a_n$}
   \psplot[plotpoints=17,linecolor=blue,linestyle=none,showpoints=true]{0}{15}{\f}
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](12,0)(12,130)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,85)(16,85)
   \rput(9,105){$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}a_n =+\infty$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile using XeLaTex, the compiler returns 170 errors, 2 warnings and generates a pdf file. Looking in the log files one can find errors like in the following lines:

```
  ! Undefined control sequence. 
   \tx@Line ...{ 0 0 /n 2 def } if (\psk@ArrowInside 
                                                  ) length 0 gt { \ifx \psk@... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ...2 ED /x2 ED x1 y1 \psk@ArrowInsidePos 
                                                  \space 1 gt { /Alpha y2 y1... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ... def /ArrowPos \psk@ArrowInsideOffset 
                                                  \space def /dArrowPos \psk... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ...ce def /dArrowPos \psk@ArrowInsidePos 
                                                  \space abs def \psk@ArrowI... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ...Pos \space abs def \psk@ArrowInsideNo 
                                                  \space cvi { /ArrowPos Arr... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ...t }{ /ArrowPos \psk@ArrowInsideOffset 
                                                  \space def /dArrowPos \psk... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?  
  ! Undefined control sequence. \tx@Line ...ace def /dArrowPos \psk@ArrowInsideNo 
                                                  1 gt {1.0 \psk@ArrowInside... l.20    \def
            \f{3 3 0.8 neg x exp mul add} ?
```

How can one remove all these errors? What is the source of all these errors? Does pstricks picture generate these erros?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PSTricks drawing not working with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614129/pstricks-drawing-not-working-with-xelatex)

Comment: Works fine for me on a current tex system. Show the complete log-file so that one can see which versions you are using.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.9.8)  8 SEP 2021 14:11
entering extended mode
**./seq.tex
(seq.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-03>