# Recent display problem with bclogo

Tags: miktex, bclogo

Since few days, I've a big problem with `bclogo` package. Previously, everything was ok but now, when I'd tried to compile, I've got this...

Here, an MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pstricks]{bclogo} % Logo pour des boîtes
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-blur} % ¨Nécessaire pour bclogo


\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcbook]{}
 test bclogo
\end{bclogo}


\end{document}
```

And the result is :

[image: Result of bclogo]

I've not the box, the logo (or the text) is not at the good place !

The log file is available here : [log file](https://uptobox.com/ewquek48576o)

Thanks !!

Comment: it should be okay again when miktex updates pstricks.

Comment: I've updated miktex, with administrator mode, with no effects...

Comment: I know, miktex lags a bit behind texlive sometimes. You will have to wait a few days.  or try lualatex https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614171/2388

Comment: But I never had this problem since few years ?! So, I'll use Overleaf this week. Hope this problem will be repaired soon.
LuaLaTeX doesn't work too, due to errors with pstricks it seems...

Comment: It can happen, one update contained a bug, and after  a few days it has been repaired and then it takes a few day to reach the tex systems. If you are in a hurry use texlive instead of miktex. It gets such updates normally faster.

Comment: Texlive isn't very convenient with Windows it appears. Thanks Overleaf !
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm on windows and use texlive without any problems. I also have miktex. There is not much difference between both systems.

Comment: Ok, thanks for precision

Comment: For information, the package pstricks has been updated.