# Problem with MikTex imposing an old version of Ghostscript

Tags: miktex, ghostscript, ps2pdf

I have installed the Ghostscript (v9.55.0), Ghostview, and installed Miktex a couple of months ago on a new computer (and updated MikTeX whenever I could). I am working on Texmaker mainly lately have configured all the paths in the settings.

I am working on a document with beamer and using lots of pstricks figures, and can't compile with pdflatex (because of pstricks issues mainly), so I am using latex+dvpis+ps2pdf. However, there are issues appearing with beamer boxes (theorems and so on).

- From what i found online, a fix would be to use "-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY" with the ps2pdf command, which works on kind of recent versions of ghostscript. However, this didn't fix my problem.
- So I went to open my .pdf file, checked its properties, and it says that the .pdf file has been made by "dvips + MikTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25"... Meaning that MikTeX forces the use of its (very old) preinstalled version of ghostscript instead of the one i had installed myself (9.55.0), and this is why the previous fix doesn't work (since it works only on more recent versions of ghostscript, and not on 9.25)...
- Therefore, I went to check online again, to try to tell MikTeX to use the correct version of GhostScript. Someone in an old thread said to put the "set MIKTEX_PREFERMIKTEXGHOSTSCRIPT=false" command in windows' cmd. It didn't work, it still compiles with the 9.25 version.
- So I searched again, and on a closed thread someone proposed to copy the good version of gswin64c.exe (= ghostscript 9.55.0) in miktex's ghostscript folder, to replace the mgs.exe (= ghostscript 9.25), after renaming it "mgs.exe" of course. This does not work for me, ps2pdf refuses to finish compiling, which is even worse now, so i went back to putting the original .mgs.exe file.

Therefore, here I am, still with no idea how to force MikTeX to use the good, new version of ghostscript, instead of the old, buggy version that is installed together with MikTeX. Has anyone got any idea?

Ps: I am really starting to wonder what is the point in being able to set the path for the good version of ghostscript (in TeXmaker, WinEdT, etc.) if MikTeX still forces the use of its own crappy version...

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: If I remember correctly I couldn't use a newer ghostscript either. Either install texlive or try to compile with lualatex, it supports pstricks now.

Comment: You might try to use `-dNOSAFER` with that version of Ghostscript.

Comment: You mean somehow the MikTeX version gets called by TeXmaker even if you put the full path to the "good" version of ps2pdf in Options > Configure TeXmaker > Commands? Are you using QuickBuild? Have you tried using a custom "User" defined QuickBuild with the full paths?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I had never used (nor seen) LuaLaTeX, but it worked like a charm, thanks!

@

Comment: the pstricks support in lualatex is rather new: last year it was still "experimental": https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614171/2388

Comment: @HerbSchulz I'm gonna try that, thanks!

Comment: @frabjous I put the full ghostscript path, but the ps2pdf link still points to miktex's (i have checked with cmd "where ps2pdf" command). In the recent version of ghostscript I have installed, there are some ps2pdf files, but no executables. I have checked the .bat file, tried to directly link it in teXMaker, but to no avail. And although I put the correct, full path to ghostscript in texmaker, MikTeX still forces the use of its own version via its ps2pdf.exe

Ps: compiling with lualatex as Ulrike mentionned works with both beamer and pstricks apparently, so no ghostscript version issues!