# pstricks not working with xelatex on TL21

Tags: xetex, texlive, pstricks

On my new installation of TL21 with ghostscript 9.53 pstricks is not working with xelatex.
I know the problem with dvipdfmx.cfg, I changed -dSAFER to -dNOSAFER

Thanks for a hint

G. Rau

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See my comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614078/2388

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, that works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PSTricks drawing not working with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614129/pstricks-drawing-not-working-with-xelatex)